# How can you speed up the performance of localhost after enabling asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Page loading on my development machine has fallen through the floor since upgrading to Rails 3.1 and enabling the asset pipeline.

I used to see page loads taking 1 or 2 seconds but they're now regularly over 10s (on localhost).

This is starting to really hamper development speed, is there a way to accelerate things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 seconds?! That's pretty slow indeed...

First of all, if `enabling the asset pipeline` means that you compress the assets in development mode, stop doing it:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.assets.compress = false
```

Then bear up until the Rails 3.2.0 release. The [changelog](https://gist.github.com/1472145) may interest you:

> Speed up development by only reloading classes if dependencies files changed. This can be turned off by setting `config.reload_classes_only_on_change` to false. José Valim

Finally can you post a sample of your logs + your config please?

Comment: Thanks Delba, I've got compression off already but will take a look at upgrading to 3.2.0.